# add a docker container to netdata docker as new node

Tags: docker

Netdata has been installed on docker container.
I tied to add new docker container into netdata.cloud as below;
I tried to run below command in host docker server

```
docker exec -it php7.4-apache2 netdata-claim.sh -token=token -rooms=my_room2 -url=https://app.netdata.cloud
docker exec -it php7.4-apache2 /usr/sbin/netdata-claim.sh -token=token -rooms=my_room2 -url=https://app.netdata.cloud
```

I tried to run below command in php7.4-apache2 container

```
sudo netdata-claim.sh -token= -rooms=my_room2 -url=https://app.netdata.cloud
```

But end up with

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "netdata-claim.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

I would like some suggestions from expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing relative paths (and not only filenames) when executing `sh`-files by adding `./`, for example:

`sudo ./netdata-claim.sh <...>`

Comment: Hi anion, 
Thanks for your reply. 
Where do I have to run ur command, either host linux or, netdata docker or php7.4-apache2 docker?

Comment: you must simply add `./` in the command you have just executed, shown in your second listing in your question.

Comment: `
bash: ./netdata-claim.sh: No such file or directory
`
Same error.
I am sorry, if my question may confuse you. I may not get the concept how does netdata work. 
First, I installed netdata on docker container. 
Then I want to monitor another container. 
They are on the same host but different containers.
first commands are run on the host
second command is run on the different container (php7.4-apache2 container but not netdata container.

Can I monitor php7.4-apache2 container from different container where netdata installed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can most certainly monitor other containers while having netdata installed as a docker container.

To claim the netdata container, you should be able to do it via running this command on the **host machine**:

```
docker exec -it netdata netdata-claim.sh -token=98FMbk9sx-22f75VU2FiC2xzoeeN8umkxDmh8zeeOKACCkevYBSCOU2B0o7g75-cUXc0QpLZ6ej-ZvSokSWelisrncFwi4RXFfpkNexBXv8UnHSDkvccjv0xjBYFPww-Vu28coQ -rooms=abb4d556-6d1f-46a1-a04d-663b86ccf4ea -url=https://app.netdata.cloud
```

Please note that the `netdata` just after `-it` is the name of the container that runs netdata, so in case the name of the container is a different one, you will have to change that part of the command(e.g `docker exec -it <container_name> ..`)

Keep us posted if you make it work!